# Compiling and linking modules using other modules

Tags: module, compilation, fortran, fortran90

I am working on a Fortran library that contains many different functions. To develop it and maintain it more easily, I have divided this library into several modules (e.g., `part1.f90`, `part2.f90`, `part3.f90`) and a main module `mylib.f90` using all these individual modules:

```
module mylib
  use part1
  use part2
  use part3
  implicit none
end module mylib
```

The idea is then to use this main module in my programs with `use mylib`. I am however having trouble compiling and linking these modules.

The modules are all contained and compiled in a directory `/mylib/src/`, which therefore also contains the corresponding `*.o` and `*.mod` files. When I compile my program in a different directory using:

```
gfortran -I/mylib/src myprog.f90 -o myprog
```

I would expect the compiler to find the required modules in the specified directory. But unfortunately, I get an error message that there are undefined references to functions that are actually contained in the submodules.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are omitting the linking of the object files in which the executable representation of your module functions (*etc*) are to be found.  With the `-I` option you're telling the compiler where to find the include files (*ie* the `.mod` files) but nowhere are you telling it to link the `.o` files that you have, I presume, already created.  A simple way to link them would be to edit your compile command along the following lines:

```
gfortran -I/mylib/src -o myprog myprog.f90 /mylib/src/part1.o /mylib/src/part2.o ...
```

I expect that if I used the command-line for compiling (I don't, I use `make` or some other build system) I'd know how to specify the path to the `.o` files only once.  Someone will probably come by here sooner or later and put us both in that particular picture, or you could break into the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was however trying to bypass the need to mention all the objects when linking my program with the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information from other websites, see for instance: 
http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Library+distribution

**The first approach** would be to compile the modules, save the `*.mod` files in a specific directory, e.g. `/usr/lib/fortran`, and create an archive `libmylib.a` containing the `*.o` files using `ar -r libmylib.a *.o`. Then, to compile my program I would add the flag `-I/usr/lib/fortran` to indicate the compiler where the modules are, so that he can find them when he encounters a `use mylib` in my code. finally, I would link my program against the archived library using the flag `-lmylib`, and indicating where the archived library is located with `-L`.

The problem with this approach is that Fortran compiled modules are compiler-dependent, which implies that we have to be careful if using different compilers or even different versions of the same compiler on a machine.

**The second approach** would be to include the modules of the library in the build directory, and compile them together with the program.

Any other suggestions are welcome!